# How do I use Redux state in a useEffect function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My basic goal is to send a api call based on a redux search state. I've found somewhat similar questions but they all seem overly complicated and I'm unable to understand their examples. I know that the `props.search` isn't populated at the time it's called; how do I get React to wait for it? I hope an explanation of why the following code doesn't work and a solution will help me understand what I'm missing.

```
redux state = {
  search: 'bar',
  posts: []
}
```

componenet.js

```
function Fu(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts(props.search)
  }, []);
  const {posts} = props;

  return (
    <div>
      posts ? ( posts.map((post) => (
      <Post post={post} key={post._id} />
      )) ) : (<p>loading...</p>
      );
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  search: state.search,
  posts: state.posts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchPosts,
}; 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(fu);
```

action.js

```
export const fetchPosts = (query) => (dispatch) => {
    console.log(query);
}
```

log  = `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!props.search)return;
    fetchPosts(props.search)
  }, [props.search]);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/8289918) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this will not work is assuming the first picture is your default redux state, when you map state to prop, posts in your component prop will be an empty array and posts will be true, which will make it go and render Post component. Since posts is an empty array and you are accessing _id in the map function, which will generate an error that says cannot access _id of undefined.

Comment: should useEffect run before the render; like component did mount? I changed the state to `posts: null` and there's no change.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your error and your reducers? the error may also with how the data is being parsed into your redux state.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the problem is when I console log  `props.search` in the  `fetchPosts` function it is `undefined`.

Comment: I saw you pass fu and not Fu into your connect function at the bottom. Have you fixed this?